# Best way to convert a .sql file to a .json or to a javascript Object or to a sequelize model file

Tags: javascript, sql, json, sequelize.js

I want ro create a accessible `JSON` or `JS-Object` out of a `.sql` file. What is the best way to do this, or are there any solutions for that available.

Or is there any good solution to create a `sequelize` model file out of a `.sql`

my .sql file:

```
CREATE TABLE `AuthenticationSettings` (
 `AUTSET_Id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `updated_at` timestamp );

CREATE TABLE `ClinicAuthentiation` (
 `CLINAUT_Id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `updated_at` timestamp );

ALTER TABLE `AuthenticationSettings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`AUTSET_Id`) REFERENCES `ClinicAuthentiation` (`AUTSET_Id`);
```

Example `JSON` that i want to create (It is just an example, i would accept any file with i can work with):

```
{
"AuthenticationSettings" : {
"type" : "create",
"fields" : {
 "AUTSET_Id" : "Integer"
...
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe your use-case? Why do you need the database-schema in that format?

Comment: teh system is using many microservices with different databases, ORMs  aso.  I want to introduce one ORM (sequelize) for every microservices. The best way is to autogenerate a sequelize .js model file out of a mysql statement. But i cant get it to work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert SQL Schema into a JSON Object then you can use [sql-ddl-to-json-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-ddl-to-json-schema) It's not very feature full but can work for your use-case. For example

```
const { Parser } = require('sql-ddl-to-json-schema');
const parser = new Parser('mysql');
 
const sql = `
CREATE TABLE AuthenticationSettings (
    AUTSET_Id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    updated_at timestamp
);
`;
 
const options = {};
const jsonSchemaDocuments = parser.feed(sql)
  .toJsonSchemaArray(options);

console.log(jsonSchemaDocuments[0])
```

that will convert and show the output as

```
{
  '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema',
  '$comment': 'JSON Schema for AuthenticationSettings table',
  '$id': 'AuthenticationSettings',
  title: 'AuthenticationSettings',
  type: 'object',
  required: [ 'AUTSET_Id' ],
  definitions: {
    AUTSET_Id: {
      '$comment': 'primary key',
      type: 'integer',
      minimum: 1,
      maximum: 2147483647
    },
    updated_at: { type: 'string' }
  },
  properties: {
    AUTSET_Id: { '$ref': '#/definitions/AUTSET_Id' },
    updated_at: { '$ref': '#/definitions/updated_at' }
  }
}
```